# How to clear sessions of all users in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, session

In magento 1 I used to clear session deleting `var/session` dir.

But how to make it in Magento 2?

`env.php` fragment:

```
'session' => 
    array (
        'save' => 'files',
    )
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/sessions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution myself.

I've changed my sessions to save to database like this:

```
'session' => 
    array (
        'save' => 'db',
    ),
```

And then I can clear session just truncationg the `session` table.

Answer (score 3):

To get folder to clear, run the command:
`php -r "var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'));"`
And then delete this folder.

Comment: It is where php stores session, but I am looking for magento sessions